# Arraylist of parcelable objects not working

Tags: android, parcelable

I created a class which implements parcelable interface. Then i created an array list of that class and pass through an intent to another activity. But when the activity tries to get the parcelable array list a run time exception is happpening

my parcelable class is

```
package com.myapps.sulu.firstapp;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
public class Details implements Parcelable {
int id = 0;
String name = "";
int number = 0;

public Details(int id, String name, int number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public Details(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.number = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeInt(number);
    dest.writeString(name);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}


public static final Creator<Details> CREATOR = new Creator<Details>() {
    @Override
    public Details createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Details(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Details[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Details[size];
    }
};
}
```

i create the array list here

```
Cursor cursor = writableDatabase.query(TestContracts.TestTable.TABLE_NAME, projection,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<Details> allDetailses = new ArrayList<Details>();
    do {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TestContracts.TestTable.ID));
        int phone_number = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TestContracts.TestTable.NUMBER));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TestContracts.TestTable.NAME));
        Details details = new Details(id, name, phone_number);
        Log.d("MSG", name + " " + id + " " + phone_number);
        allDetailses.add(details);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    Intent intent = new Intent(DbActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("values", allDetailses);
    startActivity(intent);
```

i got the exception in getParcalableArrayList line shown below

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    values = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("values");
    showRows();
```

the exception is

```
08-27 16:48:39.507    7277-7277/com.myapps.sulu.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapps.sulu.firstapp/com.myapps.sulu.firstapp.DetailsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@42a11020: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536737 at offset 124
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@42a11020: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536737 at offset 124
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2032)
        at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986)
        at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
        at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1217)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:4837)
        at com.myapps.sulu.firstapp.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:25)            
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: do you want to add the whole Cursor data to Intent's extras???? is it really what you want to do?

Comment: yes, to show the table in another activity

Comment: then pass the information "how" to get the Cursor, dont pass all the data, what if you have thousands of rows there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you fill the parcel in this order:

- `id`
- `number`
- `name`

And when you try to recreate the object from the parcel you use this order:

- `id`
- `name`
- `number`

It is important that when you put your values into a Parcel that you do it in the same order as when you read them from that Parcel. So you have to switch `name` and `number` in either the constructor you call from the Creator or in the `writeToParcel` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `readFromParcel` method in your `Details` class.